# Why is my migrated Joomla installation resulting in 404 and 500 Server Errors?

Tags: apache, iis, joomla, http-status-code-404

I just finished migrating a Joomla 3.x installation from a server running Apache to IIS. I've run into a couple of problems:

1. While the front page loads fine, every single link on the site, menu item or otherwise, results in a 404 error
2. I can log into the admin panel just fine, but when I went into the Global Config settings to disable SEF URLs to see if that would fix problem #1, I got a 500 server error when I tried to save.

What is causing this?

Many thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The IT guy had multiple versions of PHP installed and the IIS url rewrite module was corrupt and needed to be reinstalled. All is good with the world now :)